# Python 'utf-8' decoding error when not running from VS

Tags: python, utf-8

I wrote a simple string for script comparison in python, and it works fine when run from Visual Studio (I use PTVS), but when I just execute script from command line or by just running it, there is an error "utf8 codec can't decode byte". I've looked for this error around the site, and it seems to be a common one, but none of the solutions helped.
here's the code:

```
import json
import sys
import codecs

json_data=open('input_1.json')
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

names = [line.strip().split(',')[0].strip() for line in open('input_2.txt')]

output = codecs.open('out.txt',"w",'utf-8')
for name in names:
    x = [name + " - " + entry["look"] for entry in data if entry['around'] in name]
    if(len(x)>0):
        output.write(''.join(x)+'\n')
    else:
        output.write(name + ' - wtf\n')

output.close()
```

Comment: are you sure that everything in input_1.json is encoded utf-8?

Comment: Yes, I made sure. Opened all files in notepad++ and forced encoding to UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: I've spent the last 10 mins playing around with file formats of the files trying to get it to fail (in CentOS) and I can't :(  Even tried to induce this from the docs `"a\x81".decode("utf-8")` but that gave invalid json!

Comment: Update:
Characted causing the error is '©'. Once removed, there is no error returned in any case. If the character is present, visual studio will execute the script without errors, and the error will appear if the script is executed alone.

Comment: Could you post your full traceback?